# Analysis Services keep creating new database id when refresh data in PowerPivot SharePoint

Tags: sql-server, excel, sharepoint-2010, ssas, powerpivot

I have a problem with the Analysis Services..i don't know how to explain this,but I have build a cube on PowerPivot and uploaded it in my sharepoint site.my problem is,each time I reload /refresh the workbook in SharePoint, the database id in Analysis Services keep creating the new id of the database. My question is,how can I keep the original database Id even when I'm refreshing/reloading the workbook?

thanks :)

here's the example below:

[Total Registrants  Staging -Data Refresh Test Process **0f90d7a9-1547-4baf-888d-79fc30afc731**]

[Total Registrants  Staging -Data Refresh Test Process **7ecdc846-7474-4951-aaa0-ebdb77eddf7c**]

[Total Registrants  Staging -Data Refresh Test Process **8ad6b2f1-c6a0-477d-a511-b7b79a62f9d2**]

as you can see,each time I reload the workbook in sharepoint,it'll generate new id of the **Total Registrants  Staging -Data Refresh.**